# Vue-Router not loading component

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am developing a website using Vue and Vue-Router in local. Then I commit changes with git to the production server and the site files get updated.

I was making a payment status page and it's working perfectly in local, so i uploaded the changed to the production server but for some reason the component isn't being loaded on the production server. I am getting no errors.. The rest of the routes I made (were always and are still) working fine, but the new routes I made/make dont in production (again, working perfectly locally)

Does anyone have any debugging suggestions to try and figure out whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, It had to do with caching